# bilinear form that separates points.

Tags: functional-analysis, intuition

I started to read Bresiz' book on functional analysis and at some point he sais

there is a bilinear form $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$, on X × Y that separates points (i.e., $∀x\neq 0$ $∃y$ such that $\langle x, y\rangle \neq 0$ and $∀y \neq 0 ∃x$ such that $\langle x, y \rangle\neq 0$)

I don't really see the geometrical intuition behind this notion of separating points.

Comment: What you are describing is just the definition of nondegeneracy. The bilinear form is nondegenerate if $<x,y> = 0$ for all $y$ implies $x=0$. Separating points means this: For any $x,y$ that are not equal, there exists a functional $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ and $f(y) = 0$. If that was not the case, then there is no $f$ that can differentiate between $x$ and $y$ (that will imply that the bilinear product is degenerate).

Comment: @Laithy, is there a relation between $f$ and the bilinear product here?

Comment: Yes definitely. For any $f$, there exists a unique $y$ such that $f(x) = <x,y>$ for all $x$. That is the Riesz representation theorem. Thanks to that, we have that one can separate points iff the bilinear product is nondegenerate.

Comment: @Laithy, okay I am starting to get it. basically separating points means \forall x\neq y there is $f$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$. So if two points $x\neq y$ cannot be separated it means that $\forall f f(x)=f(y)$ so by Riesz that $\langle z,x\rangle= \langle z,y \rangle$ so $\langle z,x-y\rangle = 0 \forall z$. So the bilinear form is degenerated since $x-y\neq 0$. But this the same as saying $x$ and $y$ are separated by some hyperplane $f=\alpha$